# Serving Donuts at Hanachas Tefilin

Tags: tefilin, minhagim

Is there any source or sefer that mentions the origins of serving pastries in shul when a boy starts putting on tefilin?

Comment: When a boy becomes a man he has to start watching his cholesterol. The donuts are equivalent to a bachelor party - a last taste of freedom

Comment: Probably not but donuts and pastries are common breakfast items and a hanoches tefillin generally takes place in the morning

Comment: OK but who says at all that you need to serve food the day a boy starts putting on tefilin? Is this an actual minhag or just an American invention? Is it talked about in books about minhagim?